# Gauss map on trace of curve

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, differential-geometry

Suppose we have a curve $\gamma : I \to S$ where $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is an interval and $S$ is a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (not necessarily orientable). We know that the Gauss map $N$ can be locally defined at all points of $S$, but there is not necessarily a way to define it continuously on the whole surface. Can we define a map $N_I : I \to S^2$ such that $N_I(t)$ is normal to the surface $S$ at $\gamma(t)$?

Notice that $N_I$ is not necessarily $N|_{\gamma(I)}$, since for two points $t_0, t_1$ with $\gamma(t_0) = \gamma(t_1)$ it is possible that $N_I(t_0) \neq N_I(t_1)$ (indeed, this must happen necessarily if the manifold is non orientable). This question came to me as a variation of the problem 2.6.6 of Do Carmo *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces*.

Comment: Is $S$ a surface in $\mathbb{R}^2$? If so, I assume you are allowing $S$ to have boundary, as a complete surface without boundary in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is always orientable. Is $I$ an interval, or are you allowing it to be a circle?

Comment: @AlbertWood S is a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, possibly with boundary (this is the definition of Do Carmo). $I$ is an interval. I would say if $I$ was a circle this construction wouldn't be possible for non orientable manifolds, as there would be orientation-reversing loops.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible. Intuitively, at every point $s \in I$ there are two choices of unit normal to $S$ at $\gamma(s)$. Since there are no loops in $I$, it is possible to make a consistent global choice.

Using the language of vector bundles, the pullback of the normal bundle $TS^\perp$ to the interval I, $\gamma^*(TS^\perp) := \{(s,\nu) : s\in I, \, \nu \in T_{\gamma(s)}S^\perp\}$, is isomorphic to the trivial bundle, $I \times \mathbb{R}$. Therefore we may choose a global section $N: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ corresponding to a consistent choice of normal along the curve.

Comment: I don't really know anything about vector bundles. Could we do it by taking a finite family of charts $\{ \phi_i \}$ (since the curve is compact), fixing one of them (for example, $\phi_1$) and choosing in any other char the normal consistent with the orientation of $\phi_1$?

Comment: @Zanzag Yes, if you are happy that you can choose a consistent normal in each chart, then this is the right way to do it.

Comment: What would be the problem if we assumed that $I$ is a circle? I suppose in that case $N_I$ is not necessarily continuous but I don't really see how one can formalize that $N_I$ is continuous in this case.

Comment: @Zanzag for each chart on $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ from left to right, you choose the unit normal consistent with the previous choice, which overlaps on the left side. Since you are only matching with one previous choice, this is always possible.
If we instead had $I = S^1$ a circle, then the final chart would need to match with two previous choices, which isn't necessarily possible.
For an example, consider $S$ as the mobius strip, and $\gamma: S^1 \rightarrow S$ the 'equator' around the strip. It is impossible to choose a consistent normal along the curve.

Comment: OK, so the problem actually comes from defining it in a consistent way. Once you have defined it consistently, continuity is ensured, is that right?

Comment: Yes, by consistently I mean continuously :D

Comment: I understand your comment, but the charts do not need to "allign" do they? For example, even in an interval there could be a triple intersection of charts. I understand it intuitively but when it comes to formalization every argument I make for an interval stands for a circle. What would be the problem if, as I said in the previous comment, we chose the normals in all the charts in a consistent way with the first chart (this is, as the usual normal if the orientation of the chart $i$ is the same as the first, or as the opposed vector in the other case)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135673/discussion-between-albert-wood-and-zanzag).